# Compilie ruby 1.8.6 with openssl 0.9.8

Tags: openssl, ruby, centos7

I'm trying to install ruby 1.8.6 on CentOS7 and successfully finished, but ruby cannot load openssl.

My install steps are below.

Install openssl 0.9.8 from source.

```
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-0.9.8zb.tar.gz
tar xzf openssl-0.9.8zb.tar.gz
cd openssl-0.9.8zb
./config --prefix=/usr/local shared
make && make install
openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zb 6 Aug 2014
cd
```

Install ruby 1.8.6 from source.

```
# Fix timeout.rb:59: [BUG] Segmentation fault
export CFLAGS="-O2 -fno-tree-dce -fno-optimize-sibling-calls"

wget ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8/ruby-1.8.6-p420.tar.gz
tar xvfvz ruby-1.8.6-p420.tar.gz 
cd ruby-1.8.6-p420
./configure
make && make install
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2010-09-02 patchlevel 420) [x86_64-linux]
cd
```

These steps are finished without error, but ruby cannot load openssl.

```
irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'openssl'
LoadError: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl.rb:17
    from (irb):1:in `require'
    from (irb):1
```

The error shows that cannot open 'openssl.so' but the file exists at /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/openssl.so.

```
ls /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear God why? Just fix the Ruby code so that it runs in this decade.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. Here is what I did.

```
# cd to openssl directory in ruby source directory
cd ruby-1.8.6-p420/ext/openssl
ruby extconf.rb
make && make install
```